# Google Tag Manager noscript tag appears as string, why? (using react-gtm-module)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-tag-manager, next.js, netlify

I use react-gtm-module to place the Google Tag Manager Tags in a react/next.js app hosted with netlify.

The gtm script tag in the head renders perfectly. But the noscript tag in the body is rendered falsely with the iframe as string:

```
<body>
  <noscript>
    "
          <iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-XXXXXXX&gtm_auth=&gtm_preview=&gtm_cookies_win=x"
            height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden" id="tag-manager"></iframe>"
  </noscript>
  ...
</body>
```

react-gtm-module code:

```
import TagManager from 'react-gtm-module'
...
componentDidMount(){
const tagManagerArgs = { gtmId: 'GTM-NCGQVKQ' }
TagManager.initialize(tagManagerArgs);
}
```

Has anybody an idea what might be the cause?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi, could be great if you can post also how the piece of code where you insert the `noscript` gtm part.

Comment: I just added it : )

Answer (score 3):

When scripting is enabled, the `noscript` element will only contain plain text. Try disabling JS in your browser, then the text in the `noscript` tag should be parsed as HTML

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#the-noscript-element

Comment: So are you saying that the result i showed is as it should be? 
I just checked it. When javascript is disabled the noscript tag gets not rendered at all. I wonder if some other module/library might interfere with the react-gtm-module...

Answer (score 1):

If your app is only on the client side (no server-side rendering involved), then the `noscript` part is useless and will never be triggered, since it is loaded using javascript and it is only meant in case javascript is disabled.

From the package's README:

> Disabling javascript in the browser can prevent the correct operation of this library if React is only being rendered on the client side.